# I want to switch off the update or comment tone in FB.

Tags: facebook

I want to switch off the update or comment tone in FB. I get the beep sound, when any of my friends comments on an update that I have commented on or I am following. It is just irritating.

Comment: What kind of device are you using?

Comment: I am on a laptop; HP.

Answer (score 1):

Click the gear in the upper right corner of the window and go to **Account Settings**, **Notifications**, **How You Get Notifications - On Facebook - View**, and uncheck **Play a sound when each new notification is received**.  Then click **Save Changes**.

[image: Facebook Sound Notification Setting]

See also [Facebook Help](http://www.facebook.com/help/302202129901479/).